# Bootstrap text field not going 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap textfield embedded in a panel going to go to 100% remaining space-width in the panel. But this is what I get:

[image]

The blue border is the edge of the panel.

This is the code I have:

```
<div class="input-group ">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <a id="pdfUrlButton" class="input-group-btn btn btn-default go inline"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>Bestand kiezen </a>
        <input id="pdfLoc" type="text" class="form-control disabled" placeholder="Nog geen rooster gekozen">
        <input type="file" name="pdfUrl" id="pdfUrl" class="hidden"/>
    </div>
    <div id="pdfAlert" class="alert alert-danger hide">Dit is geen PDF!</div>
</div>
```

I know this question gets asked a lot, but I simply can't get it to work with the found answers.

Comment: can you create a fiddle instead of pasting an image?  It would be easier for people to inspect

Comment: you can add display: block; to the .input-group

Comment: Hmm, never did a bootstrap fiddle before, let me see how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed it with an example from their own components guide:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
.input-group {
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

but you'll more than likely want to make the selection in your css more specific so that this doesn't not apply to all elements with this class unless this is your desired style

Comment: Its hard to say exactly with only seeing a screenshot but what I did was copy your html and insert it into the panel body on the bootstrap docs page and added a display:block to the input group. Could you tell me if you're adding any custom css. If you are using only the css that comes with bootstrap then adding the display block should work, as you can see in the image ref that I posted. Need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your code in a div row and specify the full row (12 columns):

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <a id="pdfUrlButton" class="input-group-btn btn btn-default go inline"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>Bestand kiezen </a>
                <input id="pdfLoc" type="text" class="form-control disabled" placeholder="Nog geen rooster gekozen">
                <input type="file" name="pdfUrl" id="pdfUrl" class="hidden" />
            </div>
            <div id="pdfAlert" class="alert alert-danger hide">Dit is geen PDF!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That does something, however it seems to remove all padding that is normally present on an inputgroup, should it do that?

Comment: @Difusio "Rows must be placed within a .container for proper alignment and padding" http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid